# Power BI: Nested AND statement in URL filter

Tags: powerbi

I have a URL filter that looks like the following:

```
ReportSection?filter=Utility~2FID%20eq%20%27company%27
```

I need to modify this URL to add:

```
AND (Type not equal 1 AND Type not equal 2)
```

What is the correct format for this to add to the URL filter?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL filtering is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters).

Assuming `Type` comes from the `Utility` table,

```
ReportSection?filter=Utility/ID eq 'company' and Utility/Type ne 1 and Utility/Type ne 2
```